# Problem uploading file to s3 with alexusmail/laravel file manager

Tags: laravel, file-manager

I have problem when uploading file with alexusmai/laravel-file-manager.

I've cloned it from github alexusmai/laravel-file-manager and it's already connected to my cloud minio s3, but I have a problem when uploading file and got an error message appears "Path cannot be empty", I've been searching on google, but I still can't find a way to solve it.

[image]